# Using browser.pause() twice

Tags: protractor

I would like to use `browser.pause()` twice( pressing `ctrl-d` to continue in between).

Is it possible to not wrap the second `browser.pause()` in a `then()`?

```
it("browser.pause", () => {

  browser.pause(); // Protractor attaches debugger
  angularHomepage.getStartedButton.click();

  // pause hits if wrapped in then
  angularHomepage.navigateTo().then(() => browser.pause());

  // Protractor: Encountered browser.pause(), but debugger already attached.
  browser.pause();
});
```

Comment: Looks like it was fixed before, but it is reproducible again since 3.3.0 (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2206)